# Prove $f(\overline{A})=\{c \}$ while $f(A)=\{ c \}$

Tags: general-topology

"Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and $A\subset X$.  Let $Y$ be a $T_1$-space and $f:X\to Y$ be continuous. Prove $f(\overline{A})=\{c \}$ given that $f(A)=\{ c \}$"

I came up with a solution using the definitions only. It's pretty straightforward so I'm not gonna write it down here.

I wanna solve this problem by using net. Here's what I have so far,

Let $x\in \overline{A}$, then there exists a net $(x_i)_{i\in I}\subset A$ such that $x_i \to x$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f(x_i)\to f(x)$ or $(c)\to f(x)$. And then I'm stuck. I couldn't and don't think that in a $T_1$-space the limit is unique. So am I on the right track? Can you help me with this approach. Thank you

Comment: I think you're not using net, rìght? Since I did look at it and all I think is the approach not using net

Comment: A net with values in a closed set cannot converge to a point outside the closed set.

Answer (score 1):

$f[A]  =\{c\}$ says that $A \subset f^{-1}[\{c\}]$ and the latter is a closed set as the inverse image of a closed set (by $T_1) under a continuous function.

So $\overline{A} \subset \overline{f^{-1}[\{c\}]} = f^{-1}[\{c\}]$ which means that $f[\overline{A}] = \{c\}$.

No real need for nets.
But if you insist: let $x \in \overline{A}$. There exists a net from $A$, say $n:I \rightarrow A$ ,such that $n$ converges to $x$. Then $f \circ n$ is a net (the image net) which only assumes the value $c$. So the limit is $c$ (as $\{c\}$ is closed, a net with values in a closed set cannot converge to a point outside) and this must equal $f(x)$ by continuity of $f$...